# Can I filter the user list in FBFriendPickerViewController?

Tags: ios, facebook-ios-sdk

The FBFriendPickerViewController lets a user select a subset of their facebook friends. I'd like to filter or manipulate that list some. For example, it would be useful if I can somehow highlight which friends already have my application installed.

Anyone have a code snippet which does this?

Answer (score 1):

From the docs [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sdk-reference/iossdk/3.0/class/FBFriendPickerViewController/) it states that "The delegate can also be used to filter the friends to display in the picker.".  So I would assume that in your Delegate you do something like this:

```
- (BOOL)friendPickerViewController:(FBFriendPickerViewController *)friendPicker shouldIncludeUser:(id<FBGraphUser>)user
{ 
    if ([myArrayOfValidUsers containsObject:user])
        return YES;

    return NO;
}
```